# Why setting superglobal variable $GLOBALS['foo'] doesn't work?

Tags: php, scope, superglobals

The following code produces a warning:

```
<?php
$GLOBALS['foo'] = "Example content<BR><BR>";
echo $foo; // that works!
Test();

function Test()
{
    echo $foo; // that doesn't work!
}
?>
```

The warning is:

`Notice: Undefined variable: foo`

How come ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inside the function, `$foo` is out of scope unless you call it as `$GLOBALS['foo']` or use `global $foo`. Defining a global with `$GLOBALS`, although it improves readability, does not automatically reserve the variable name for use in all scopes.  You still need to explicitly call the global variable inside lower scopes to make use of it.

```
function Test()
{
    echo $GLOBALS['foo'];

    // Or less clear, use the global keyword
    global $foo;
    echo $foo;
}
```

It's even possible to have both a local and a global `$foo` in the same function (though not at all recommended):

```
$GLOBALS['foo'] = "foo! :)";
function getFoo()
{
  $foo = "boo :(";
  echo $GLOBALS['foo'] . "\n"; // Global $foo
  echo $foo;            // Local scope $foo since it has no global keyword
}

getFoo();
// foo! :) 
// boo :(
```

Review the [PHP documentation on variable scope](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) and the [`$GLOBALS` documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.globals.php) for more examples.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to refer to it via the $GLOBALS array all the time. Read about [variable scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) to get the full descriptve answer.

```
<?php
$GLOBALS['foo'] = "Example content<BR><BR>";
echo $foo; // that works!
Test();

function Test()
{
    echo $GLOBALS['foo']; // that doesn't work!
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can change your code to:

```
function Test() {
    global $foo;

    echo $GLOBALS['foo'];
    echo $foo;
}
```

you have to declare which global variables you access from your PHP function. See: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php